# orWhere Query in Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

I was trying to find product which aren't free products and product status is active ie, 1  but the problem is it doesn't work the way i want with the following Query. it gives the products collection both inactive and free with the matches i want. How can i get the appropriate output by modifying following Query?
Here `$query` is the search keyword

```
$products = DB::table('products')                       
            ->where('products.name' , 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('products.tags','like','%'.$query.'%')               
            ->where('products.status','=',1)    
            ->where('products.price','!=',0)            
            ->groupBy('products.id')
            ->latest()
            ->paginate(3);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to encapsulate your orWhere :

```
$products = DB::table('products')
        ->where(function($q) use ($query){    
            $q->where('products.name' , 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('products.tags','like','%'.$query.'%');
        })               
        ->where('products.status','=',1)    
        ->where('products.price','!=',0)            
        ->groupBy('products.id')
        ->latest()
        ->paginate(3);
```

Which should be render something like

```
SELECT * FROM 'products' 
WHERE (
    products.name like '%query%' OR 
    products.tags like '%query%'
) AND 
products.status = 1 AND 
products.price <> 0
GROUP BY products.id
```

Comment: I have already tried with this but it throws Error

Comment: What error is throws ?